# How to make an event scheduler that goes back every day but not Wednesday?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to create two events with requirements:

- Events that run at 6 a.m. every day
- Events that run every Wednesday at 6 a.m

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS dayrest
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS '2023-04-07 06:00:00'
DO
    IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) = 4 THEN 
        UPDATE `Todo` SET done=0;
    END IF
    IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) NOT LIKE 4 THEN
        UPDATE `Todo` INNER JOIN `Raid`
        ON Todo.`raidName` = `Raid`.name
        SET done=0 
        WHERE `Raid`.`resetType`="day"
        UPDATE `Todo` SET done=0;
    END IF
END
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibwef.png)

> errorMessage : "END" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE, BEGIN, BINLOG, CACHE, ...

I don't know what the error is and why...

------------ edit ----------

```sql
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS dayrest
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS '2023-04-07 06:00:00'
DO
IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) = 4 THEN 
    -- work all todo reset
    UPDATE `Todo` SET done=0;
ELSE 
    -- work only day type rest
    UPDATE `Todo` INNER JOIN `Raid`
    ON Todo.`raidName` = `Raid`.name
    SET done=0 
    WHERE `Raid`.`resetType`="day"
END IF
```

##### Syntax Errors

> Statement is incomplete, expecting ;

> "ELSE" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ALTER, ANALYZE, BEGIN, BINLOG, CACHE, ...

Comment: 1) You loose BEGIN which matches last END. 2) Use not two IF-THEN but IF-THEN-ELSE. PS. There are syntax errors in your SQL code. PPS. What is the reason to update some rows whereas the next query updates all rows with the same value?

Comment: Please post your error as text.  Images are for graphical information.

Comment: @Akina On Wednesday, I reset all the todo
The rest of the day is to initialize only certain todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS dayrest
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
        STARTS '2023-04-07 06:00:00'
    DO  
        IF DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) = 4 
            THEN UPDATE `Todo` SET done=0;
        ELSE-- work only day type rest
            UPDATE `Todo` INNER JOIN `Raid`
            ON Todo.`raidName` = `Raid`.name
            SET done=0 
            WHERE `Raid`.`resetType`="day";
        END IF
|
delimiter ;
```

it work for me no syntax errors

Comment: *it work for me no syntax errors* But it is not correct nevertheless. You create compound statement which consists from more than one SQL statement. In this case it is safe to use BEGIN-END which encloses this compound statement action body.